# disabling hyper-v in windows 10 causes complete network failure

Tags: networking, hyper-v, tcpip, windows-10

I have disabled (uninstalled) Hyper-V so I can run VM-Ware and have completely lost the network. It shows the cable connected but there is no internet connection. Ive tried a different cable and have reset my switch and router with no success. If done the netsh commands to reset the ip, ipv4, ipv6, winsock and I have killed the two winsock keys in the registry. Was unable to edit the nettcpip.inf file - access was denied (even after running notepad as administrator).

I am running out of internet searches and ideas. Does anyone have an idea of what I need to do (short of re-installing windows)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally ended up restoring from a restore point. I am sure there is something else that can be done instead, unfortunately, I needed the network on that computer immediately.

Answer (score 5):

I uninstalled all my `Network adapters` in `Device Manager` and then I right-clicked and chose `Scan for hardware changes` and my existing/standard adapter came back and was working right-away.

Comment: Yup this works for me.

Comment: This worked for me too. I did not check the “delete drivers” option, just uninstalled the devices and scanned for changes.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem after removing Hyper-V, and resolved it by reconfiguring my netowork adaptor. I had to do this because I discovered the netsh commands had left things in an invalid state.

According to, to pick one example of many, [this blog](http://www.geeksinphoenix.com/blog/), the following netsh command "Removes all user configured IPv4 (Internet Protocol version 4) settings":

```
netsh int ip reset
```

However, what I found was that while this command did clear the static IP address I'd set, it left the option selected to use a static IP address:

[image]

Once I re-entered my static IP settings, the yellow triangle disappeared and the network came back.

To satisfy myself that netsh had really done this, I repeated the whole exercise, adding and removing Hyper-V, and exactly the same thing happened when I gave the above netsh command. It seems netsh is somewhat buggy. Its use for TCP/IP functionality should anyway be viewed as deprecated: while looking at the netsh commands I noticed advice to this effect from Microsoft, which doesn't show up when full netsh commands are used, but only when you go to the "int" (interface") level in netsh:

```
C:\WINDOWS\system32>netsh
netsh>int
In future versions of Windows, Microsoft might remove the Netsh functionality
for TCP/IP.

Microsoft recommends that you transition to Windows PowerShell if you currently
use netsh to configure and manage TCP/IP.

Type Get-Command -Module NetTCPIP at the Windows PowerShell prompt to view
a list of commands to manage TCP/IP.

Visit http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=217627 for additional information
about PowerShell commands for TCP/IP.
netsh interface>ip
netsh interface ipv4>
```

Comment: So what is the proper Powershell command?

Answer (score 0):

When Hyper-V is enabled, only Hyper-V Extensible Virtual Switch is selected but nothing else. Uninstall Hyper-V just remove the current selection and nothing is selected. Manually selecting whatever you need there should fix the issue. You better have another working machine for reference.
[When Hyper-V is enable](https://i.stack.imgur.com/C4Vyk.png)

Answer (score 0):

Here are the step that finally worked for me:

1. Rebooted into safe mode
2. Opened the Device Manager
3. Disabled all of the Hyper-V devices.
4. Rebooted.
5. Removed Hyper-V from the Add/Remove Windows Features.
6. Rebooted.... and all was well.